# Uncaught SyntaxError: Unexpected reserved word await

Tags: vuejs3, inertiajs

my app.js is like this I tried to run npm run dev but my pages did not show and there was an error. can someone please help me

```
import { createApp, h } from 'vue'
import { createInertiaApp } from '@inertiajs/vue3'
import MainLayout from './Layouts/MainLayout.vue3'

createInertiaApp({
  resolve: name => {
    const pages = import.meta.glob('./Pages/**/*.vue', { eager: true })
    const page = await pages[`./Pages/${name}.vue`]()
    page.default.layout = page.default.layout || MainLayout

    return page
  },
  setup({ el, App, props, plugin }) {
    createApp({ render: () => h(App, props) })
      .use(plugin)
      .mount(el)
  },
})
```

I tried this solution but I still keep getting the same error
https://blog.csdn.net/qq_38157825/article/details/125148577

Answer (score 0):

Perhaps you can read more details in [Await from MDN](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Operators/await#description)

> Because await is only valid inside async functions and modules, ...

As far as I know `await` should be used with `async`, in your case maybe you can try adding `async` before createInertiaApp like this.

```js
async createInertiaApp({
  ...
    const page = await pages[`./Pages/${name}.vue`]()
  ...
})
```

Comment: Yeah it's the one I'm missing. Thank you!

Answer (score 0):

Await can only be used in async functions. In your case:

```
createInertiaApp({
  resolve: async (name) => {
    const pages = import.meta.glob('./Pages/**/*.vue', { eager: true })
    const page = await pages[`./Pages/${name}.vue`]()
    page.default.layout = page.default.layout || MainLayout

    return page
  },
  setup({ el, App, props, plugin }) {
    createApp({ render: () => h(App, props) })
      .use(plugin)
      .mount(el)
  },
})
```

From what I see, an async resolve function *should* be allowed but I may be wrong

Comment: Thanks! I followed this and it work I did forget the put async function

Answer (score 0):

I finally made it work. I was missing the async function

```
createInertiaApp({
  resolve: async (name) => {
    const pages = import.meta.glob('./Pages/**/*.vue')

    const page = await pages[`./Pages/${name}.vue`]()
    page.default.layout = page.default.layout || MainLayout

    return page
  },
```